# Inserting multiple key value pair data under single _id in cloudant db at various timings?

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, cloudant, node-red

My requirement is to get json pair from mqtt subscriber at different timings under single_id in cloudant,  but I'm facing error while trying to insert new json pair in existing _id,  it simply replace old one. I need at least 10 json pair under one _id. Injecting at different timings.

Comment: you should show the structure of the document(s) you want to insert. It will be easier to answer. Likely it is only a matter of loading the existing document from Cloudant (the document will have a _rev attribute maintained by Cloudant to handle save conflict), updating this document and inserting it again.

Comment: Though i'm new to cloudant,  struggling in it.  If we update the data means only existing will be modified.  How new record will be inserted in to existing _id which already holds one record?  I know it's possible to have more record under one _id  but whether it's possible to update the same _id by adding more records?

Comment: If it not clear,  I can briefly explain

Answer (score 4):

First, you should make sure about your architectural decision to update a particular document multiple times. In general, this is discouraged, though it depends on your application. Instead, you could consider a way to insert each new piece of information as a separate document and then use a map-reduce view to reflect the state of your application.

For example (I'm going to assume that you have multiple "devices", each with some kind of unique identifier, that need to add data to a cloudant DB)

PUT

```
{
  "info_a":"data a",
  "device_id":123
}

{
  "info_b":"data b",
  "device_id":123
}

{
  "info_a":"message a"
  "device_id":1234
}
```

Then you'll need a map function like

`_design/device/_view/state`

```
{
  function (doc) {
    emit(doc.device_id, 1);
}
```

Then you can `GET` the results of that view to see all of the "info_X" data that is associated with the particular device.

GET account.cloudant.com/databasename/_design/device/_view/state

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"28324b34907981ba972937f53113ac3f","key":123,"value":1},
{"id":"d50553d206d722b960fb176f11841974","key":123,"value":1},
{"id":"eaa710a5fa1ff4ba6156c997ddf6099b","key":1234,"value":1}
]}
```

Then you can use the query parameters to control the output, for example

GET account.cloudant.com/databasename/_design/device/_view/state?key=123&include_docs=true

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"28324b34907981ba972937f53113ac3f","key":123,"value":1,"doc":
  {"_id":"28324b34907981ba972937f53113ac3f",
     "_rev":"1-bac5dd92a502cb984ea4db65eb41feec",
     "info_b":"data b",
     "device_id":123}
  },
{"id":"d50553d206d722b960fb176f11841974","key":123,"value":1,"doc":
  {"_id":"d50553d206d722b960fb176f11841974",
     "_rev":"1-a2a6fea8704dfc0a0d26c3a7500ccc10",
     "info_a":"data a",
     "device_id":123}}
]}
```

And now you have the complete state for `device_id:123`.

### Timing

Another issue is the rate at which you're updating your documents.

Bottom line recommendation is that if you are only updating the document once per ~minute or less frequently, then it could be reasonable for your application to update a single document. That is, you'd add new key-value pairs to the same document with the same `_id` value. In order to do that, however, you'll need to GET the full doc, add the new key-value pair, and then PUT that document back to the database. You must make sure that your are providing the most recent `_rev` of that document and you should also check for conflicts that could occur if the document is being updated by multiple devices.

If you are acquiring new data for a particular device at a high rate, you'll likely run into conflicts very frequently -- because cloudant is a distributed document store. In this case, you should follow something like the example I gave above.

Comment: If my payload is {"_id":"100","No":"1"} here in cloudant it will create a _id 100 and store No :1 but if I try to insert {"_id":"100","No":"2"} under same_id it simply override the existing No : 1. I need both the records in Same document.  How come it possible?

Comment: It should not be possible for you to insert a second document with the same  "_id" value. That should fail with a 409 error. Second, you cannot construct a JSON document with two keys that are the same. You cannot make a document like this { _id:100, "No":1, "No":2}.  You could put all your numbers into an array, like { _id: 100, "No": [1, 2]}. But, I suggest you follow the example I laid out above.

Comment: What if we keep inserting (PUT) device info for the same attribute continuously - e.g. I keep inserting docs with key "info_a", but when I retrieve, I only want the latest doc with key "info_a". How to write map-reduce to get only the latest doc for each device attribute

Answer (score 0):

Example flow for the second approach outlined by @gadamcox for use cases where document updates are not required very frequently:

> [...] you'd add new key-value pairs to the same document with the same `_id` value. In order to do that, however, you'll need to GET the full doc, add the new key-value pair, and then PUT that document back to the database.

Your application first fetches the existing document by id:  (https://docs.cloudant.com/document.html#read)

```
GET /$DATABASE/100

{
 "_id": "100",
 "_rev": "1-2902191555...",
 "No": ["1"]
}
```

Then your application updates the document in memory

```
{
 "_id": "100",
 "_rev": "1-2902191555...",
 "No": ["1","2"]
}
```

and saves it in the database by specifying the `_id` and `_rev`  (https://docs.cloudant.com/document.html#update)

```
PUT /$DATABASE/100

{
 "_id": "100",
 "_rev": "1-2902191555...",
 "No":["1","2"]
}
```